# ЗАДАЧА. ПОДСЧЁТ СВОЙСТВ

Tags: javascript

Нужно выполнить рефакторинг функции `countProps(object)` используя метод `Object.keys()` и, возможно, но необязательно, цикл `for...of`.

Это задачка из курса. Автопроверки.

- Объявлена функция `countProps(object)`
- Вызов `countProps({})` возвращает `0`
- Вызов `countProps({ name: "Mango", age: 2 })` возвращает `2`
- Вызов `countProps({ mail: "poly@mail.com", isOnline: true, score: 500 })` возвращает `3`
- Функция подсчитывает только собственные свойства объекта
- Функция использует метод `Object.keys()` и, возможно, цикл `for...of`

Делаю это:

```js
function countProps(object) {

  let propCount = 0;
  const keys = Object.keys(object);

  for (const key of keys) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      propCount += 1;
    }
  }
  return propCount;
}
```

Но автопроверка не пропускает:

Функция использует метод `Object.keys()` и, возможно, цикл `for...of` -   (ЗДЕСЬ МАТЮКАЕТСЯ).

- Объявлена функция `countProps(object)`
- Вызов `countProps({})` возвращает `0`
- Вызов `countProps({ name: 'Mango', age: 2 })` возвращает `2`
- Вызов `countProps({ mail: 'poly@mail.com', isOnline: true, score: 500 }})` возвращает `3`
- Функция подсчитывает только собственные свойства объекта *(ТУТ ВСЕ ПИШЕТ СДЕЛАНО ВЕРНО)*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.
Застрял долго уже на этой ерунде.
А дальше доступа нет к следующим задачам(((

Comment: Я запустил ваш код, он работает. На что у вас ругается?

Comment: Честно говоря, весь код функции можно уложить в одну строчку `return Object.keys(object).length;`, и при этом он будет удовлетворять всем условиям. А автопроверки могут глючить, сам с таким сталкивался, когда учился. Вроде всем условиям ваш код удовлетворяет

Comment: function countProps(object) {
  let propCount = 0;
const keys = Object.keys(object);

  return Object.keys(object).length;
}  Спасибо огромное!)) Сдвинулся с мертвой точки. Этот вариант приняли проверки)